# Dockerizing R (Shiny) application

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I am trying to dockerize an R(Shiny) application and I can't seem to figure out what I might be doing wrong.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean

# python dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install tensorflow==2.10.0

## working directory
WORKDIR /app

# install renv and restore packages
RUN Rscript -e 'install.packages("renv")'
COPY renv.lock .
RUN Rscript -e 'renv::restore()'

# copy the app to the image
COPY . .

# expose port
EXPOSE 3838

# run app on container start
CMD ["Rscript", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

Get the error below at the execution point `CMD ["Rscript", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]`

the error

```
# Bootstrapping renv 1.0.2 ---------------------------------------------------
- Downloading renv ... 
OK
- Installing renv  ... 
OK


- One or more packages recorded in the lockfile are not installed.
- Use `renv::status()` for more details.
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘shiny’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
```

I know why little R but this seems to my like the shiny package cannot be found. What is it that I am doing wrong.

Comment: So your renv.lock has your required packages and you're not being able to install some of those packages, one of those being shiny. You could add a `renv::status()` after your `renv::restore()` to have a better grasp of what's happening

Answer (score 0):

I had recently some problems to run shiny app developed with `renv` in docker, perhaps it will help if I will share some decisions I made, however I'm not sure if there are really connected with your problem:

1. From the project directory, I have removed `renv` folder and file `.RProfile` - so basically everything created by `renv` except of `renv.lock`.

My Dockerfile was (simplified a little):

(my folder containing shiny app is named `my_app`)

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

RUN R -e "install.packages('renv', repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))"

WORKDIR /srv/shiny-server/

COPY ./my_app/renv.lock ./renv.lock

COPY ./my_app ./my_app

ENV RENV_PATHS_LIBRARY renv/library

RUN R -e "renv::restore()"
```

At the end of the Dockerfile, I have added:

```
RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server

USER shiny
```

But this is optionally, I added this so the application has rights to write files.

I didn't store `Dockerfile` in the project directory, but this is probably irrelevant (I know very little about Docker).